# How to run a http server which serves a specific path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplehttpserver

this is my Python3 project hiearchy:

```
projet
  \
  script.py
  web
    \
    index.html
```

From `script.py`, I would like to run a http server which serve the content of the `web` folder.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) is suggested this code to run a simple http server:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

but this actually serve `project`, not `web`. How can I specify the path of the folder I want to serve?

Comment: Have you considered running `python3 -m http.server -d /path/to/web/dir` on command line to do the job? Props to @kyle-barron who gave this perfect solution in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43292151/638546) deep below.

Comment: I suggest this is the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58217918/835098

Comment: @AkseliPalén I get `server.py: error: argument port: invalid int value: '/media/EHD/web_root'` error when I run that in Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal (with python3.6.9)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In Python 3.7 [`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` can take a `directory` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000
DIRECTORY = "web"


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=DIRECTORY, **kwargs)


with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

and from the command line:

```
python -m http.server --directory web
```

---

To get a little crazy... you could make handlers for arbitrary directories:

```
def handler_from(directory):
    def _init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, directory=self.directory, **kwargs)
    return type(f'HandlerFrom<{directory}>',
                (http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler,),
                {'__init__': _init, 'directory': directory})


with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler_from("web")) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Better to use `http.server.HTTPServer` (in exactly the same way as `socketserver.TCPServer`)

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30516693/1599699

Comment: Note that if you're calling this from a Windows shortcut, then the "Start in" property of the shortcut will define what's the *current working directory* where `web` will be searched for. That is, if the command line of your Windows shortcut is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "python -m http.server --directory web"`, then in the shortcut properties, make sure to leave the "Start in" field **empty** so that it'll consider `web` as relative to the path of the shortcut file, rather than `\System32\cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 86):

If you just want serve static file you can do it by running SimpleHTTPServer module using python 2:

```
 python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Or with python 3:

```
 python3 -m http.server
```

This way you do not need to write any script.

Comment: Note that you can also add a port at the end to specify the port of the server.

Comment: further note; you have to have an `index.html` or `index.htm` file in the directory you're running the server from in order for it to be served; otherwise you get a directory list.

Comment: OP asks how to run it at specific folder path, not from present working directory.

Comment: There's a directory argument to `http.server`. So you can do `python3 -m http.server -d /path/to/web/dir`

Comment: While this answer was accepted by the owner of the question as being the best answer, I think it should not be the best answer. The question was asking for a way how to code this in python and not how to invoke it from the command line.

Comment: i wish to run a `index.py` or `main.py` as the default in a `./www` folder. the file is `www/index.py` what do i do?

Comment: This is completely different situation. Here we serve content of the files which you probably do not want. I guess you want to execute the file?

Answer (score 52):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

> This class serves files from the current directory and below, directly
>   mapping the directory structure to HTTP requests.

So you just need to change the current directory prior to starting the server - see [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

eg:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import os

PORT = 8000

web_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'web')
os.chdir(web_dir)

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thank you! Note: I added try: `httpd.serve_forever(); except KeyboardInterrupt: pass; httpd.server_close()` to actually close the port.

Comment: Thanks. Its worked. But how can I get the Host address for this? I mean to say that how can I get 0.0.0.0:8000 instead of my local router address 192.168.0.100:8000

Comment: @roipoussiere You rather should use `with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:`, this way it closes automatically after being used

Comment: For future readers: Andy Hayden's solution below is less 'hacky', and probably preferred, since it doesn't rely on side-effects.

Answer (score 31):

You also can run the command line with

```sh
python3 -m http.server -d web 8000
```

Comment: or to see all supported parameters try `python3 -m http.server --help`

Answer (score 26):

There's a shorter method for Python 3+:

```
import functools
    
Handler = functools.partial(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, directory='/my/dir/goes/here')
```

Comment: this is a very cool way to do this and it works for me. I'd definitively recommend this as the best answer!

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'directory'`

Comment: I get the same error in Python 2.7. It worked for me on Python 3.8.

Comment: Stop using Python 2 :)

Answer (score 21):

Just for completeness, here's how you can setup the actual server classes to serve files from an arbitrary directory:

```
try
    # python 2
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer as BaseHTTPServer
except ImportError:
    # python 3
    from http.server import HTTPServer as BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


class HTTPHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    """This handler uses server.base_path instead of always using os.getcwd()"""
    def translate_path(self, path):
        path = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.translate_path(self, path)
        relpath = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())
        fullpath = os.path.join(self.server.base_path, relpath)
        return fullpath


class HTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer):
    """The main server, you pass in base_path which is the path you want to serve requests from"""
    def __init__(self, base_path, server_address, RequestHandlerClass=HTTPHandler):
        self.base_path = base_path
        BaseHTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
```

Then you can set any arbitrary path in your code:

```
web_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'web')
httpd = HTTPServer(web_dir, ("", 8000))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 8):

Another easy method to serve from a specific directory.

Since you really only need to set the `directory` parameter for the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`, you can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to *prepare* the handler class without instantiating the class.

```py
from functools import partial
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from pathlib import Path


def start_httpd(directory: Path, port: int = 8000):
    print(f"serving from {directory}...")
    handler = partial(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, directory=directory)
    httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', port), handler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score -12):

**If** you just need a modern web **static server**,
`deno` is an alternative `file server` without any `code`.

### install deno with single line

https://github.com/denoland/deno_install#deno_install

### install `file server` with single line

```sh
deno install --allow-net --allow-read https://deno.land/std@0.125.0/http/file_server.ts
```

### use deno `file-server`

```rb
file_server . --port=<port>
# Downloading https://deno.land/std@0.125.0/http/file_server.ts...
# HTTP server listening on http://0.0.0.0:<port>/
```

read more https://deno.land/manual/examples/file_server#using-the-codestdhttpcode-file-server