# path issues with python server

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, relative-path

In a directory containing an `index.html` I type `python -m http.server 8085` and get:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8085 (http://0.0.0.0:8085/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2018 08:56:40] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2018 08:56:40] "GET /dist/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2018 08:56:40] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2018 08:56:40] "GET /assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

but inside the `index.html`the importing lines are

```
<link href="../../../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../../../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Those paths are correct relative to that directory, if I apply linux `ls`to the paths between the quotes from there, it finds them.

Inside the console of the browser, it is complaining similarly:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:8085/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js”.
0.0.0.0:8085:131
```

Yes, 131 is the line with that import statement, but why is it ignoring the  path in there?

Comment: Seems you want to access a directory level higher than your initialized root level?

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "initialized root level"? I would think that `"../../../../"` is _lower_ than `"."` but maybe have missed something. How can this be fixed?

Comment: `http.server` cannot access the directory level higher than current one. Otherwise their will be a huge security problem as people can use `http://host/relative/path` to get every files on your computer. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Why do you think it will be lower than "."? ".." means parent directory.

Comment: Okay @Sraw thanks, have clarified what higher and lower mean, parents, grandparents etc are higher, child directory is lower. Have worried about that security risk before, so good to know why it won't do it. Have changed to a higher directory and tried to run it with [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39801780/4288043) but there are still path issues, but for further testing will probably just move those libraries into a _lower_ rather than _higher_ directory.