# How to automatically start a python http server

Tags: python, django, selenium, twilio-api, httpserver

I am using python http.server 80 to expose my downloaded files to my twilio whatsapp bot
is there a way that as my django-twillio app starts it automatically runs the server on port 80 as well
`python -m http.server 80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this code to your `django-twilio app` will programmatically start your server on localhost:80

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 80), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thank you,to add on my question i want the server to expose my Downloaded folder to twillio ,so this automatically starts the server ,how can it also expose the downloads folder at the same time

Comment: Yea you can do this, I would recommend searching SO for "serve directory in python". There are some good answers out there, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531444/9465781). Hope that helps!