# Cannot run Python3 HTTPServer on ARM processor

Tags: python, python-3.x, arm, odroid

I recently bought [Odroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODROID) [XU4](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G143452239825), a single-board computer with an [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) CPU. I try to run a simple web server using [HTTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) on Python3.

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

This code runs well on my Mac machine. But when I try to run this on Odroid XU4, I got this error message.

```
$ python3 webserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Can anyone explain why I got this error? For your information, I’ve attached the information about the OS and Python interpreter.

```
$ uname -a
Linux odroid 4.9.44-54 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 20 20:24:08 UTC 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linu

$ python 
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 18 2017, 17:48:00)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) it would seem that the contextmanager protocol (`with ...`) form for `TCPServer`'s base class (and therefore `TCPServer` was added in python3.6.  This is not available in python3.5

> Changed in version 3.6: Support for the context manager protocol was added. Exiting the context manager is equivalent to calling `server_close()`.

Fortunately, you can use the previous approach.  This roughly means taking your with statement and turning it into a plain assignment:

```
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```